# Исправить ошибки в программе python

Tags: python-3.x

ТЗ:
Необходимо исправить ошибки в коде,внести корректировки, чтобы программа заработала.

Сначала получить у человека ожидаемое число баллов. После этого программа вычисляет свой ориентир: если число меньше 50, то оно удваивается. Если число больше или равно 50, то ориентиром будет число 100. Также выбирается, какой текст напечатать, в зависимости от введённого числа. В результате печатается этот текст и число. Например, если введено 35, программа ответит: "А постарайся набрать 70 баллов!". Если введено 70, программа ответит: "Давай стремиться к максимуму: 100 баллов!"

`

```
a = input "Сколько баллов ты рассчитываешь набрать в этом тесте?"
if a < 50:
a = 2 * a
s = "А постарайся набрать "
    else:
    a = 100
    s = "Давай стремиться к максимуму: "
        print s + str(a) + " баллов!"
```

`

Comment: Что у Вас не получается, укажите в вопросе, будьте так добры.

Comment: необходимо исправить код, чтобы он работал

Comment: В каком месте у Вас возникли проблемы, укажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: В этом и проблема, я не знаю что где и как исправлять

Comment: Код работает? Нет. Если нет, то в чем это выражается? Если выдает ошибку (а он выдает), то в самую первую очередь необходимо прочитать текст этой ошибки.. Если непонятно, что он означает, то вбить в поисковик и почитать пару ссылок, там будет разъяснено, что это за ошибка и как ее исправлять.  У вас не возникнет НИ ОДНОЙ ошибки, которая не была бы уже 100500 раз описана в интернетах. Так нужно делать до тех пор, пока не перестанут появляется ошибки. Если после этого код все еще работает не так, как вам хочется, то вот тогда можно начинать спрашивать.

Answer (score 0):

При правильном форматировании программа должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
a = int(input("Сколько баллов ты рассчитываешь набрать в этом тесте?"))
if a < 50:
    a = 2 * a
    s = "А постарайся набрать "
else:
    a = 100
    s = "Давай стремиться к максимуму: "
print s + str(a) + " баллов!"
```

Кроме того, если у вас Python 3, то print - это функция и надо брать её аргументы в скобки:

```
print(s + str(a) + " баллов!")
```